# Days of the week not in sequence on line chart x axis power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, linechart

I am currently having trouble to plot the days of the week in right order on x-axis. It shows not in sequence no matter what I try. It shows categorical type and never works when I try to switch to continuous. Can someone help on how to achieve this?  I am using sort by day to count the values for each day and using relative filter to select last 7 days of the week.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the days in text and order (Mon, Tue,... Sun) then you have to have a [Day of Week] column in numbers with 1 = Monday 2 = Tuesday (or wich ever day you want the week to start with gets the 1) in your Date table. Under the modeling tab there's a sort-by drop down menue. Make sure you have the Day column selected in the table pane and then select order by [Day of week]. This should change the sorting of the days from alphabetically to by the day of week number.